# iterate over array value not display in phtml

Tags: php, xml, phtml, array

I´m trying to display Ebay GetSingleItem response (http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/GetSingleItem.html) and I´m having problems displaying array ["ItemSpecifics"]. The call is working ok and I´m receiving the following information:

```
["ItemSpecifics"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListArrayType)#208 (2) {
          ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(1) {
            ["NameValueList"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#129 (5) {
              ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(8) {
                [0] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#207 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(6) "Format"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#191 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(10) "DVD/HD-DVD"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
                  }
                  ["attachment":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["data"] => NULL
                    ["mimeType"] => NULL
                  }
                }
                [1] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#65 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(5) "Genre"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#152 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(16) "Sci-Fi & Fantasy"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
                  }
                  ["attachment":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["data"] => NULL
                    ["mimeType"] => NULL
                  }
                }
                [2] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType)#180 (2) {
                  ["values":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType":private] => array(2) {
                    ["Name"] => string(7) "Edition"
                    ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#253 (5) {
                      ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                        [0] => string(10) "Widescreen"
                      }
                      ["position":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => int(0)
                      ["class":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(44) "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\NameValueListType"
                      ["property":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(5) "Value"
                      ["expectedType":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => string(6) "string"
                    }
```

So in my controller I put the following information:

```
$event = array();
            foreach($item->ItemSpecifics->NameValueList as $data){
                $event[] = $data;
            }
```

I set the data using:                     `->setCollection($event)`

and in my html page (view) I used:

```
<?php $res = $this->getCollection() ?>
<?php foreach ($res as $row)
{
    echo "<tr id='0' class='0'>
                    <td>
                        <div class='name'>" . $row->Name . " </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class='value'>" . $row->Value . " </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
} ?>
```

but my problem is that the data included in NAME only is retrieved. the information in Value is not retrieved into the view. just to put more in clear with an example. The information = FORMAT is displayed but DVD/HD-DVD is not.

```
["Name"] => string(6) "Format"
                        ["Value"] => object(DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType)#191 (5) {
                          ["data":"DTS\eBaySDK\Types\UnboundType":private] => array(1) {
                            [0] => string(10) "DVD/HD-DVD"
                          }
```

Comment: As I can see the Value is an object, so you need to call `$row->Value->data[0]`.

Comment: @michael thanks for your reply. I´m receiving  Fatal error: Cannot access private property when using $row->Value->data[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->Value` is an object, and the `->Value->data` property is marked as private. That means you cannot read it from outside (without doing reflection) but instead need to call a relevant method to read its value. Looking at [the implementation of UnboundType](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk/blob/master/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/UnboundType.php) we see that you should be able to read the `->Value` object as if it was an array (they implement the ArrayAccess interface). The data you want is in position 0 so try this:

```
$row->Value[0]
```